# css list item display uniform width

Tags: html-lists, css

I'm working on a horizontal menu with a vertical submenu. I have most of the display features set the way I want, but I'm running into trouble with displaying the submenu items with the same width. I want to display them as a nice, even block, but I'm left with a jagged edge on the right side of the submenu.

Here's a snippet of the html I'm using for the menu itself.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >item with sub</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" >sub item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" >sub item 2 which is longer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" >sub item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I'm not sure which part of the css I'm using might be affecting the width of the dropdown menu, so here's everything.

```
.navbar {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #999;
}

.navbar li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar li > ul {
  top: 42px;
  left: 0px;
}

.navbar li:hover,
.navbar li:hover > a,
.navbar li a:hover{
  background-color: #999;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.navbar li:hover ul,
.navbar li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasotastic/yso6v2po/

Possible that this is a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find a similar question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set 100% width to `<li>` to adjust with content width.

```
.navbar li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yso6v2po/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can set a width to li and use white-space: normal. Then you will have a fixed width and break the phrase if it is bigger than the width.

Your code modified:

```
.navbar li ul li {
  width:200px;
  white-space:normal;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yso6v2po/3/